# Filter sheet data based on a column value exists in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Ive a sheet with data similar to this

```
Users  Role
-----------
Name1   a
Name2   b
Name3   c
Name4   d
Name5   e
Name6   f
Name7   g
```

Another Sheet

```
Users Req
------
Name4
Name6
Name7
```

So the sheet data should be filtered based on the column values exists in second sheet. So after filtering the first sheet looks like this.

```
Users   Role
-------------
Name4    d
Name6    f
Name7    g
```

How can we achieve like this

Comment: Use VLOOKUP formula in a column and then filter on non-error values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the values in the Other sheet in an array, in my code below it's `FilterArr`, and then you can `AutoFilter` according to the values in this array by using `Criteria1:=FilterArr`.

More explanations inside the code below as comments:

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAccordingtoValuesInOtherSheet()

Dim Sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim FilterArr As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long

Set Sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify to your sheet's name where you have the data you want to filer
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") ' modify to your sheet's name where you have values you want to use for the filter

With sht2
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column A

    FilterArr = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value2)  ' get the values from the second sheet to an array
End With

With Sht1
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column A

    ' set the Auto-Filter by column A, to the values in the array
    .Range("A1:B" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FilterArr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With

End Sub
```